# Disable Windows style scroll bars in Chromium

Tags: chrome, scrolling

Is there any way to disable the supremely irritating Windows-style scroll bar in Chromium web browser?

By that, I mean the way that the scroll bar stops scrolling up and down (and jerks back to the place in the page where you first grabbed the scroll bar) if you move the mouse *too far* to the left or right.

I hate this on Windows, and I absolutely despise it on Chromium in Linux.  I'd like the scrollbar to work exactly the same as it does in every other app on my XFCE desktop, and not give a damn about horizontal mouse movement.

Comment: Aside from an add-on such as [ReScroller](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/07/30/change-the-size-and-style-of-google-chromes-scrollbar-with-rescroller/), nothing else comes to view.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, thanks, but it looks like that just changes the appearance of the scrollbar, not the behaviour.

Comment: The other possibilities which I found all were limited to CSS tweaks; the description of this one implied that it went beyond that.